Weibull Pareto Distribution
Weibull Pareto is a new distribution and I want to check that this mixture of distribution belongs to exponential family. For this purpose I have used the structure given by Dobson, as  $g(y;\tau)=\exp\{a(x)b(\tau)+c(\tau)d(x)\}$
$g(x)=\frac{\beta c}{x}\{\beta \log (\frac{x}{\theta})\}^{c-1}\exp \{-(\beta \log (\frac{x}{\theta})^c\}$
I got $a(x)=\log(x)-\log (\lambda)$, $c(\tau) =-(\alpha \log (\frac{x}{\lambda}))$, $b(\tau) = (c-1)\log (\alpha)$ and $d(x)= -\log (x)$, where $\lambda=\beta c$. which shows that it belongs to exponential family. Is this approach correct?
